# "rosservice list" and "info" from c++

Tags: c++, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I access to the functions of "rosservice" from a c++?
I need to know the existing services and information about each service.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151611/%22rosservice-list%22-and-%22info%22-from-c++/) by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2014-04-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A simple way might be to call rosservice.

Alternatively you can use the [ROS Master API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API). In this case getSystemState.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-04-10**:
are there some examples of that?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-11**:
Probably in roscpp? This might help: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1master.html

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-04-13**:
Thanks, I posted the solution.
Your link was really usefull.

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-04-13**:
But, how can I get information about a service?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With this code, you can get the name of all the running services and copy them to an array.

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "node");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue req = "/node";
    XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue res;
    XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue pay;

    if (ros::ok() == true)
    {
ros::master::execute("getSystemState",req ,res ,pay ,true);
    std::string state[res.size()];
      for(int x=0 ; x<res[2][2].size() ; x++)
      {
          std::string gh = res[2][2][x][0].toXml().c_str();
          gh.erase(gh.begin(), gh.begin()+7);
          gh.erase(gh.end()-8, gh.end());
          state[x] = gh;
      }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) with karma: 131 on 2014-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2